# Jackson deserializing recursive object

Tags: json, serialization, recursion, jackson, deserialization

I have a recursive object Node.java which I am able to serialize using Jackson but unable to deserialize it back.

**Node.java**

```
    public class Node {
        private final String id;
        private final Map<String, Node> embeddedNodes;

        public Node(String id, Map<String, Node> embeddedNodes) {
            this.id = id;
            this.embeddedNodes = embeddedNodes;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public Map<String, Node> getEmbeddedNodes() {
            return embeddedNodes;
        }
}
```

**Jackson serializer**

```
public static class NodeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Node> {
        @Override
        public void serialize(Node node, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException{
            jgen.writeStartObject();
            jgen.writeStringField("id", node.getId());

            Map<String, Node> embeddedNodesMap = node.getEmbeddedNodes();
            if (!embeddedNodesMap.isEmpty()) {
                jgen.writeObjectFieldStart("embeddedNodes");
                for (Map.Entry<String, Node> entry : embeddedNodesMap.entrySet()) {
                    jgen.writeObjectField(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                }
                jgen.writeEndObject();
            }

            jgen.writeEndObject();

        }
    }
```

**Sample Node instance**

```
Node node0 = new Node("0", Maps.<String, Node>newHashMap());
Map<String, Node> embeddedNodes1 = Maps.newHashMap();
embeddedNodes1.put("zero", node0);
Node node1 = new Node("1", embeddedNodes1);
Node node2 = new Node("2", Maps.<String, Node>newHashMap());
Map<String, Node> embeddedNodes = Maps.newHashMap();
embeddedNodes.put("first", node1);
embeddedNodes.put("second", node2);
Node node3 = new Node("3", embeddedNodes);

String jsonStr = mapper.writeValueAsString(node3);
```

**JSON generated:**

```
{
    "id": "3",
    "embeddedNodes": {
        "second": {
            "id": "2"
        },
        "first": {
            "id": "1",
            "embeddedNodes": {
                "zero": {
                    "id": "0"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I am unable to write corresponding deserializer for this, any help is appreciated.

```
class NodeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Node> {
        @Override
        public Node deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
            //how do we write this??
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you find solution for that?

Answer (score 4):

@vinodv26 In **NodeDeserializer** it's not the most efficient way to use the `ObjectMapper` class to parse (again) the JSON of the embedded `Node`. Instead of:

```
Node embedNode = mapper.readValue(jsonNode.toString(), Node.class);
```

It's better to use:

```
Node embedNode = jp.getCodec().treeToValue(jsonNode, Node.class);
```

Or, if what you were looking for is to simply ignore the `embeddedNodes` attribute when it's empty, you can use `mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY)` or annotate the `Node` class with `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)`. This way you don't need custom serialization or deserialization classes, but you need to remove the `final` modifier in the `Node` attributes and add an empty constructor and setters.

Answer (score 0):

After a few attempts I came up with the following deserializer but not sure if this is the right way to do this:

```
private static class NodeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Node> {
        @Override
        public Node deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
            JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
            String id = node.get("id").asText();
            Map<String, Node> embeddedNodes = Maps.newHashMap();
            JsonNode embeddedNodesJsonNode = node.get("embeddedNodes");
            if (embeddedNodesJsonNode != null) {
                Iterator<String> embeddedElementNames = embeddedNodesJsonNode.fieldNames();
                while (embeddedElementNames.hasNext()) {
                    String embedName = embeddedElementNames.next();
                    JsonNode jsonNode = embeddedNodesJsonNode.get(embedName);
                    Node embedNode = mapper.readValue(jsonNode.toString(), Node.class);
                    embeddedNodes.put(embedName, embedNode);
                }
            }

            return new Node(id, embeddedNodes);
        }
    }
```